# Error while creating a brand new react native app (MacBook Pro M1, MacOS 14.1)

Tags: react-native, rubygems, cocoapods

I'm working with a Mac M1 with the version 14.1 of macOS Sonoma.

I'm trying to create a new react native application but I'm facing this error:

```
✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✖ Installing Ruby Gems
error Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/Users/arnaud/Projects/JournalClone/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/json-2.6.3/ext/json/ext/generator
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory:
/Users/arnaud/Projects/JournalClone/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/json-2.6.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20231115-60112-w264l5
sitelibdir\=./.gem.20231115-60112-w264l5 clean

current directory:
/Users/arnaud/Projects/JournalClone/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/json-2.6.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20231115-60112-w264l5
sitelibdir\=./.gem.20231115-60112-w264l5
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.bundle
ld: warning: -multiply_defined is obsolete
ld: warning: ignoring file
'/Users/arnaud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/libruby.3.0.dylib': found architecture
'arm64', required architecture 'x86_64'
ld: Undefined symbols:
  _rb_ary_entry, referenced from:
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      _generate_json_array in generator.o
  _rb_attr_get, referenced from:
      _cState_aref in generator.o
  _rb_cArray, referenced from:
      _generate_json in generator.o
  _rb_cFalseClass, referenced from:
      _generate_json in generator.o
      _json_object_i in generator.o
  _rb_cFloat, referenced from:
      _generate_json in generator.o
      _generate_json in generator.o
      _json_object_i in generator.o
  _rb_cHash, referenced from:
      _cState_from_state_s in generator.o
      _mObject_to_json in generator.o
      _mHash_to_json in generator.o
      _mArray_to_json in generator.o
      _mInteger_to_json in generator.o
      _mFloat_to_json in generator.o
      _mString_to_json in generator.o
      ...
  _rb_cInteger, referenced from:
      _generate_json in generator.o
      _json_object_i in generator.o
  _rb_cNilClass, referenced from:
      _generate_json in generator.o
      _json_object_i in generator.o
  _rb_cObject, referenced from:
      _Init_generator in generator.o
  _rb_cString, referenced from:
      _generate_json in generator.o
      _json_object_i in generator.o
  _rb_cSymbol, referenced from:
      _generate_json in generator.o
      _json_object_i in generator.o
      _json_object_i in generator.o
  _rb_cTrueClass, referenced from:
      _generate_json in generator.o
      _json_object_i in generator.o
  _rb_check_convert_type, referenced from:
      _cState_configure in generator.o
  _rb_check_type, referenced from:
      _cState_indent_set in generator.o
      _cState_space_set in generator.o
      _cState_space_before_set in generator.o
      _cState_object_nl_set in generator.o
      _cState_array_nl_set in generator.o
      _cState_max_nesting_set in generator.o
      _cState_depth_set in generator.o
      ...
  _rb_check_typeddata, referenced from:
      _cState_initialize in generator.o
      _cState_init_copy in generator.o
      _cState_init_copy in generator.o
      _cState_indent in generator.o
      _cState_indent_set in generator.o
      _cState_space in generator.o
      _cState_space_set in generator.o
      ...
  _rb_class_name, referenced from:
      _mString_to_json_raw in generator.o
      _mString_to_json_raw_object in generator.o
  _rb_class_new_instance, referenced from:
      _cState_from_state_s in generator.o
      _mObject_to_json in generator.o
      _mHash_to_json in generator.o
      _mArray_to_json in generator.o
      _mInteger_to_json in generator.o
      _mFloat_to_json in generator.o
      _mString_to_json in generator.o
      ...
  _rb_convert_type, referenced from:
      _cState_configure in generator.o
  _rb_data_typed_object_zalloc, referenced from:
      _cState_s_allocate in generator.o
  _rb_define_alias, referenced from:
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
  _rb_define_alloc_func, referenced from:
      _Init_generator in generator.o
  _rb_define_class_under, referenced from:
      _Init_generator in generator.o
  _rb_define_method, referenced from:
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      ...
  _rb_define_module, referenced from:
      _Init_generator in generator.o
  _rb_define_module_under, referenced from:
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      ...
  _rb_define_singleton_method, referenced from:
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
  _rb_eArgError, referenced from:
      _cState_init_copy in generator.o
  _rb_enc_associate, referenced from:
      _mHash_to_json in generator.o
      _mArray_to_json in generator.o
      _mInteger_to_json in generator.o
      _mFloat_to_json in generator.o
      _mString_to_json in generator.o
      _mTrueClass_to_json in generator.o
      _mFalseClass_to_json in generator.o
      ...
  _rb_enc_get, referenced from:
      _generate_json_string in generator.o
  _rb_enc_str_asciionly_p, referenced from:
      _generate_json_string in generator.o
  _rb_error_arity, referenced from:
      _cState_initialize in generator.o
      _mObject_to_json in generator.o
      _mHash_to_json in generator.o
      _mArray_to_json in generator.o
      _mInteger_to_json in generator.o
      _mFloat_to_json in generator.o
      _mString_to_json in generator.o
      ...
  _rb_ext_ractor_safe, referenced from:
      _Init_generator in generator.o
  _rb_float_value, referenced from:
      _generate_json_float in generator.o
  _rb_funcall, referenced from:
      _cState_from_state_s in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      _cState_aref in generator.o
      _cState_aref in generator.o
      _cState_aref in generator.o
      ...
  _rb_gc_register_mark_object, referenced from:
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
  _rb_hash_aref, referenced from:
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      ...
  _rb_hash_aset, referenced from:
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      ...
  _rb_hash_foreach, referenced from:
      _generate_json_object in generator.o
  _rb_hash_new, referenced from:
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      _mString_to_json_raw in generator.o
      _mString_to_json_raw_object in generator.o
  _rb_id2str, referenced from:
      _json_object_i in generator.o
  _rb_id2sym, referenced from:
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      _cState_configure in generator.o
      ...
  _rb_intern, referenced from:
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      ...
  _rb_intern2, referenced from:
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
  _rb_iv_get, referenced from:
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
  _rb_ivar_set, referenced from:
      _cState_aset in generator.o
  _rb_obj_class, referenced from:
      _mString_to_json_raw in generator.o
      _mString_to_json_raw_object in generator.o
  _rb_obj_is_kind_of, referenced from:
      _cState_from_state_s in generator.o
      _cState_from_state_s in generator.o
      _mObject_to_json in generator.o
      _mObject_to_json in generator.o
      _mHash_to_json in generator.o
      _mHash_to_json in generator.o
      _mArray_to_json in generator.o
      _mArray_to_json in generator.o
      ...
  _rb_path2class, referenced from:
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _Init_generator in generator.o
      _generate_json_string in generator.o
      _generate_json_string in generator.o
      _generate_json_string in generator.o
  _rb_raise, referenced from:
      _cState_init_copy in generator.o
      _generate_json_object in generator.o
      _generate_json_array in generator.o
      _generate_json_string in generator.o
      _generate_json_float in generator.o
  _rb_require, referenced from:
      _Init_generator in generator.o
  _rb_respond_to, referenced from:
      _generate_json in generator.o
  _rb_str_cat, referenced from:
      _cState_aset in generator.o
  _rb_str_concat, referenced from:
      _cState_aref in generator.o
      _cState_aset in generator.o
  _rb_str_dup, referenced from:
      _cState_aset in generator.o
  _rb_str_export_to_enc, referenced from:
      _generate_json_string in generator.o
  _rb_str_intern, referenced from:
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      _cState_aref in generator.o
      _cState_aset in generator.o
  _rb_str_new, referenced from:
      _cState_indent in generator.o
      _cState_space in generator.o
      _cState_space_before in generator.o
      _cState_object_nl in generator.o
      _cState_array_nl in generator.o
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
      ...
  _rb_str_new_static, referenced from:
      _cState_indent in generator.o
      _cState_space in generator.o
      _cState_space_before in generator.o
      _cState_object_nl in generator.o
      _cState_array_nl in generator.o
      _cState_aref in generator.o
      _cState_aset in generator.o
      ...
  _rb_str_substr, referenced from:
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
  _rb_string_value_cstr, referenced from:
      _cState_to_h in generator.o
  _rb_string_value_ptr, referenced from:
      _fbuffer_append_str in generator.o
  _rb_sym2id, referenced from:
      _cState_aref in generator.o
      _cState_aset in generator.o
      _json_object_i in generator.o
  _rb_usascii_encoding, referenced from:
      _generate_json_string in generator.o
  _rb_utf8_encoding, referenced from:
      _mHash_to_json in generator.o
      _mArray_to_json in generator.o
      _mInteger_to_json in generator.o
      _mFloat_to_json in generator.o
      _mString_to_json in generator.o
      _mTrueClass_to_json in generator.o
      _mFalseClass_to_json in generator.o
      ...
  _ruby_xfree, referenced from:
      _cState_indent_set in generator.o
      _cState_indent_set in generator.o
      _cState_space_set in generator.o
      _cState_space_set in generator.o
      _cState_space_before_set in generator.o
      _cState_space_before_set in generator.o
      _cState_object_nl_set in generator.o
      _cState_object_nl_set in generator.o
      ...
  _ruby_xmalloc, referenced from:
      _cState_init_copy in generator.o
      _cState_init_copy in generator.o
      _cState_init_copy in generator.o
      _cState_prepare_buffer in generator.o
      _cState_prepare_buffer in generator.o
      _cState_prepare_buffer in generator.o
      _cState_prepare_buffer in generator.o
      ...
  _ruby_xmalloc2, referenced from:
      _cState_init_copy in generator.o
      _cState_init_copy in generator.o
      _cState_init_copy in generator.o
      _cState_init_copy in generator.o
      _cState_init_copy in generator.o
      _cState_init_copy in generator.o
      _cState_init_copy in generator.o
      _cState_init_copy in generator.o
      ...
  _ruby_xrealloc2, referenced from:
      _cState_init_copy in generator.o
      _cState_init_copy in generator.o
      _cState_init_copy in generator.o
      _mTrueClass_to_json in generator.o
      _mFalseClass_to_json in generator.o
      _mNilClass_to_json in generator.o
      _cState_prepare_buffer in generator.o
      _cState_prepare_buffer in generator.o
      _cState_prepare_buffer in generator.o
      _cState_prepare_buffer in generator.o
      _cState_prepare_buffer in generator.o
      _cState_prepare_buffer in generator.o
      ...
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [generator.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/arnaud/Projects/JournalClone/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/json-2.6.3 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/arnaud/Projects/JournalClone/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-22/3.0.0/json-2.6.3/gem_make.out

/Users/arnaud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:120:in
`run'
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:53:in
`block in make'
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:45:in
`each'
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:45:in
`make'
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:42:in
`build'
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:188:in
`build_extension'
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:222:in
`block in build_extensions'
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:219:in
`each'
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:219:in
`build_extensions'
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:839:in
`build_extensions'
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:76:in
`build_extensions'
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in
`install'
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:203:in
`install'
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in
`install'
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
`install_from_spec'
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:130:in
`do_install'
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:121:in
`block in worker_pool'
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in
`apply_func'
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in
`block in process_queue'
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
`loop'
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
`process_queue'
/Users/arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/worker.rb:90:in
`block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing json (2.6.3), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  cocoapods was resolved to 1.14.2, which depends on
    cocoapods-core was resolved to 1.14.2, which depends on
      algoliasearch was resolved to 1.27.5, which depends on
        json
✖ Installing Ruby Gems
error Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?os=macos&platform=android and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
```

Node version: v18.18.2
NPM version: 9.8.1
Ruby version: ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [arm64-darwin22]

Can someone help me with this issue please ?